# Pandas Multiindex Groupby on Columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, multi-index

Is there anyway to use groupby on the columns in a Multiindex. I know you can on the rows and there is good [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-with-multiindex) in that regard. However I cannot seem to groupby on columns. The only solution I have is transposing the dataframe.

```
#generate data (copied from pandas example)
arrays=[['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
```

Now I will try to groupby columns which fails

```
df.groupby(level=1)
df.groupby(level='first')
```

However transposing with rows works

```
df.T.groupby(level=1)
df.T.groupby(level='first')
```

So is there a way to do this without transposing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to specify the axis in the `groupby` method:

```
df.groupby(level = 1, axis = 1).sum()
```

[image]

Or if you mean groupby level 0:

```
df.groupby(level = 0, axis = 1).sum()
```

[image]